# How to use chr() function with unicode symbols?

Tags: delphi, unicode

I know that if I want to add an ASCII character in a `string` like a black space, for example, all I need to do is to add with a call to `CHAR(32)` and the space will be added to the `string`.

But what if I want to put the *infinite* symbol **∞** (U+221E) how should I do it?

*If I paste it into a literal string like 'infinite is ∞' then Delphi wants to change the file to UTF8.*

Comment: Use `#$221E` or `Char($221E)`, I'm sure you see the pattern. But I'm not sure what you mean with *wants to change the file*

Comment: @TomBrunberg: When you right-click on the Code Editor, you can choose the encoding used to save the file.  If the source code contains raw Unicode characters in it, the IDE will try to switch the encoding to UTF-8 automatically to prevent loss of Unicode data.

Comment: Yes, @Remy I know you can select encoding (I have actually used it in some projects with various built in languages) but I have always selected it manually before adding foreign texts. I did not know about the automatic change. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Char` is a data type, so `Char()` is a typecast, not a function.  `Chr()` is a function.

In D2009+, you can use either:

- `Char($221E)` or `Char(8734)` (in earlier versions, use `WideChar()` instead)
- `Chr($221E)` or `Chr(8734)`
- `#$221E` or `#8734` character constants
- [`TCharacter.ConvertFromUtf32()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Character.TCharacter.ConvertFromUtf32)
- [`TCharHelper.ConvertFromUtf32()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Character.TCharHelper.ConvertFromUtf32)
- `'∞'`. There is nothing wrong with using this in code and letting the IDE decide how to save it. This is actually the preferred solution.  The only time you would need to avoid this is if you are using other tools to process your source files and they don't support UTF-8 files.